# SQL 2008 Server agent cant see perfmon counters

Tags: sql-server-2008, perfmon

I am trying to create a new SQL server agent alert to capture "SQLServer:General Statistics|Processes Blocked||>|5' but it looks like alert creation GUI is not able to see any perfmon counters as in the following picture: 
[image]

The drop downs for Object, counter and instance are empty.
I can't even create the alert using TSQL as follows:
[image]
I can see these counters collecting data in perfmon.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to work through this ["SQL Server – Missing Performance Counters: A consolidated list of known issues"](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214203627/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/varund/archive/2010/06/25/sql-server-missing-performance-counters-a-consolidated-list-of-known-issues.aspx) sorry.

I'm surprised this still happens: I last saw this with SQL Server 7/2000 years ago.

Comment: Nice link. Had a lot of deep info about perfmon counters.