# SQL Server and Perfmon

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, perfmon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL 2008 Server agent cant see perfmon counters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/sql-2008-server-agent-cant-see-perfmon-counters)

I'm trying to setup SQL Server Perfmon counters on a Windows Server 2003 with SQL Server 2005 SP3.  I'd like to run counters on the following:

SQLServer:Buffer Manager - Buffer cache hit ratio
SQLServer:Buffer Manager - Page life expectancy
SQLServer:General Statistics - User Connections
SQLServer:Memory Manager - Memory Grants Pending

But SQL Server does not even show up as a "Performance Object" in the drop down box in Perfmon.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: please see the details from [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/sql-2008-server-agent-cant-see-perfmon-counters). Seems you're not the only one.

Comment: The community has spoken. So closed.